# APK slower than .py on same device

Tags: python, kivy, apk, buildozer

A few days ago I did a python app with kivy, consisting on simple dot strings that grow when the screen is touched and decrease when not.

The thing is I've tested the .py file on Pydroid 3 on my mobile phone and works perfectly, but when converted to apk with buildozer the app seems to be slower, and the dots don't grow as fast as expected.

I´ve used Clock.schedule_interval of 0.005, maybe that has to do with this issue? Maybe when I run .py that interval is supported but not when apk? or is it something I ignore about how apk are built?

Here´s the link to the github repo in case someone wants to test it by themselves. I don´t paste the code here because I´m not sure if this issue has something to do with my code itself or just with the way an apk works:
https://github.com/Setibs/Juego-Visual

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.